# Can apps be developed, installed, and debugged onto an actual iPad Pro using ONLY Visual Studio & Xamarin on Windows 10 computer WITHOUT using a Mac?

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Can a C# app prototype be developed on my iPad Pro by using ONLY Visual Studio with Xamarin, on my Windows 10 Pro computer without buying (ie. using) a Mac?

Initially, for rapid development of non-distribution prototype, I want to use only VS 2017 Pro & Xamarin on Windows 10 to develop and test an app on my iPad Pro 12.9".

App will talk to other system components by WiFi, and utilize new iPad Pro features like pen and its high quality screen, for augmented reality.

Can get Mac later, in order to deploy on Apple store.

Can I truly develop, deploy onto actual iPad, and debug 100% with only VS & Xamarin, and without Mac and Xcode?

This [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/) about its Xamarin Live Player is confusing to me because it reads "the source code is interpreted" which I don't want, and later it reads "The app runs right on your phone or tablet." is I want.

Comment: I come from react-native and the docs say "Unfortunately, Apple only lets you develop for iOS on a Mac. If you want to build an iOS app but you don't have a Mac yet, you can try starting with the Android instructions instead." I guess it is the same for xaramin unfortunately

Comment: No, You can compile Xamarin.iOS based assemblies on just Windows for syntax checking, but you have to have a Mac w/Xcode's build tools to actually create the iOS app and/or ipa. Xamarin Live skirts this limitation slightly as you can design XAML UIs, etc.. without a Mac, but it has a lot of limitations and the features you want to use would not work in Live... you need a Mac...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a mac is required to build and debug iOS apps.
However, VSTS does allow you access to a mac build host which can build and deploy to TestFlight and the AppStore, if required (and if configured correctly). This won't allow you to debug and step through your code on a device or in the iOS Simulator, however. For that you need the Mac with High Sierra and the latest XCode installed.
Xamarin Live Player is in preview only and is only really useful for simple apps at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer is the company needs to buy me a new Mac.  Yum.

The bad news is that it's back to using Xcode again.  Two years ago, the star rating of Xcode on Apple Store was a mere 2-stars.   It would be nice if the tool to develop on iOS was as easy to use as iOS.  But, that's what Stackoverflow is for, I guess.   :)

Comment: Technically you do not have to use Xcode, Visual Studio just needs access to the build tools. I personally do use it for the Interface Builder as Visual Studio/Xamarin version of it has some shortcoming (and "issues" in Asset creation, etc..)

Comment: You can use Rider aswell...

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the existing answers/comments are correct I thought I'd add my own experience with this

If, like me, you won't use the mac for anything other than a build server for xamarin, I can say that a mac mini is fine for this, and will allow you to build apps. Just make sure you connect visual studio on your PC to the mac.

It's also worth noting, that more recently Visual studio team services has started using a hosted macOS build host. I haven't used this myself as I bought a mac mini, but in theory, if you use VSTS you might be able to build and deploy your iOS apps. I would suggest that you check it out.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vsts/pipelines/apps/mobile/xamarin?view=vsts&tabs=vsts
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/11/16/cloud-hosted-mac-agents-for-ci-cd-pipelines/

Sadly this has always been the case with xamarin and it's the way apple licensing works.

Comment: Is Mac mini same speed as Mac Pro?